# How to delete or allow users to signup in unconfirmed users in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using aws to manage the users in my application.
I have a bug.If user close the app without verify their account the user can't able to re-signup using the same account because the user account is already exist and the user state is unconfirmed.

But I want to delete the unconfirmed user account based on the time period.I did not get any reference.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the unconfirmed users by calling a lambda function every 7 days using CloudWatch event trigger. In the lambda function you can use listUsers api to list all the cognito users and adminDeleteUser api to delete the unconfirmed users.

Comment: I am doing this now and it's absolutely terrifying. Without the check for status=UNCONFIRMED, you delete every user in your user pool. 

I have 3 redundant checks that the user status=UNCONFIRMED with giant scary comments - just in case I accidentally screw up one of the lines of code. Or someone else after I'm gone. I really wish Amazon would provide a "delete unconfirmed users after X days feature".

Comment: I think a better strategy is to use a lambda trigger during signup to delete that individual's account if it's not confirmed in a certain period of time.  less terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do so manually within AWS / Cognito / User Pools / {your_pool} / General Settings / Users and Groups / Users.  Click the user of interest, click "Disable User" and then a delete button will appear.